# UAC turns off on Windows 10 when log in to the AD domain

Tags: active-directory, uac, windows-10

When my Windows 10 logs in to the AD domain of our company, UAC are turned off. Which is annoying and prevent apps from Windows Store to run.

This happens to everyone in our company. This is not happening with prevoius versions of Windows (7, 8), only to those with Windows 10.

AD domain was reinstalled recently, GPO is set to default.

I spent hours online looking for answer, I tried few advices how to set GPO, but nothing helped.

Has anyone a solution or an advice or a tip? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any reason you don't simply use the Windows 10 GPO templates and set UAC to enabled?

Comment: I didn't hear of them, any link? and what about previous Win versions, is it backward compatible?

Comment: You're going to need someone who knows about computers, group policy, windows networks etc.  Hire a professional.  Or use Google.

Comment: Thank you for constructive comment. Now, can you guide me where exactly in GPO templates is Enabling of UAC? I got and installed them already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835564%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Enable the GPO where the Registry Key is `"EnableLua"`

to only use this for Windows 10, add the following wmi filter to your GPO but **attention!** - the wmi filter is for the whole GP, not just for `EnableLua`! So if you put a WMI filter into your GroupPolicy Object, only windows versions declared in wmi filter will accept the GPO. Others will ignore it.

```
select * from Win32_OperatingSystem where Version like "10.%"
```